# Looping through each cell in excel/csv sheet

Tags: c#, .net, excel

This question is related to my last post ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44828935/remove-non-ascii-characters-using-microsoft-office-interop-excel?noredirect=1#comment76639851_44828935)). I want to go through each cell so that I can clean my sheet of non-ascii value (function ReturnCleanASCII ) is being used for this. However I am getting a null value when I am going through the cells.

Code

```
foreach (Excel.Range range in xlRange.Cells){
          Console.WriteLine(range.Value2.ToString());
}
```

I am using the code above to go through each cell. Is this a incorrect way to go through each cell?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\username\Desktop\Error Records.csv");
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

            int lastUsedRow = xlWorksheet.Cells.Find("*", System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious,
                false, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value).Row;

            int lastUsedColumn = xlWorksheet.Cells.Find("*", System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious,
                false, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value).Column;

            int lastColumnCount = lastUsedColumn;



            for (int i = 1; i <= lastUsedColumn; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= lastUsedRow; j++)
                {
                    xlWorksheet.Cells[j, (lastColumnCount + 1)] = "Testing data 134";
                }
            }

            foreach (Excel.Range range in xlRange.Cells)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(range.Value2.ToString());
            }


            xlWorksheet.Cells[1, (lastUsedColumn + 1)] = "Title";
            xlWorkbook.Save();
            //cleanup
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            //rule of thumb for releasing com objects:
            //  never use two dots, all COM objects must be referenced and released individually
            //  ex: [somthing].[something].[something] is bad

            //release com objects to fully kill excel process from running in the background
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlRange);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);

            //close and release
            var data = ReturnCleanASCII(xlWorksheet.ToString());
            xlWorkbook.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\Errors_four.csv".Trim(), Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV);
            xlWorkbook.Close();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);

            //quit and release
            xlApp.Quit();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);

        }

        public static string ReturnCleanASCII(string s)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.Length);
            foreach (char c in s.ToCharArray())
            {
                if ((int)c > 127) // you probably don't want 127 either
                    continue;
                if ((int)c < 32)  // I bet you don't want control characters 
                    continue;
                if (c == ',')
                    continue;
                if (c == '"')
                    continue;
                sb.Append(c);
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

error:

> Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

stacktrace:

```
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\username\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 44
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: @Dai, sorry about the wrong tag.

Comment: What does the stacktrace tell you?

Comment: @JoePhillips, it just reads the first row.

Comment: @gavsta707, yes. It breaks on Console.Writeline code with error
 Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Comment: Stacktraces don't read things. They express the error. You need to share that with us if you want us to have any clue what is happening

Comment: @JoePhillips, please check the edits for stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Convert.ToString(range.Value2)` rather than `range.Value2.ToString()`

See: [Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference - Empty Excel Cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235162/cannot-perform-runtime-binding-on-a-null-reference-empty-excel-cells)

Comment: I found this by copying and pasting your error message and then adding the word "excel" to it. It was the first result in google.

Comment: Thank you for the help and I did try that. I guess I have been stuck on it for a while so might have missed that.